# Google sheets sumif with odd data

Tags: google-sheets

I have sales data that gives me dates in a bad format. Every new sale gets automatically added to the sheet. Looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Order 1 | 2022-12-02T02:09:37Z | $1025.19 |
| Order 2 | 2022-12-02T01:25:15Z | $873.65 |

This will continue on for all sales. Now the date format is UTC for whatever reason and I can't adjust that, so within this formula I have to subtract 6 hours to get it to central time. I'm trying to create an auto-updating chart that shows an average day for 7 days, so I'm trying to do a sumif formula.

Here's what I have on Sheet2:

```
=sumif(Sheet1!C:C,index(split((index(split(Sheet1!B:B,"T"),1)+index(split(left(Sheet1!B:B,19),"T"),2))-0.25,"."),1),A1)
```

Where A1 is a single date. Testing this with one date and not the range shows that it does match. When I do the range, the total comes to 0, even though multiple different dates should match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include few more data and then show your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `A1` has the value: `2022-12-02T02:09:37Z`
Apply this formula:

```
=LAMBDA(RAW,TUNEHOUR,
 LAMBDA(DATE,TIME,
  TEXT((DATE&" "&TIME)+TUNEHOUR/24,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
 )(TEXT(INDEX(RAW,,1),"yyyy-mm-dd"),REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(RAW,,2),"Z",""))
)(SPLIT(A1,"T"),-6)
```

returns:

```
2022-12-01 20:09:37
```

And assume you have a set of data like this:
[image: data]

you can apply this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(DATES,AMOUNTS,START,END,DFORMAT,TFORMAT,SKIPBLANK,TUNEHOUR,
  LAMBDA(DATES,AMOUNTS,DTFORMAT,START,END,
   LAMBDA(DATES,TIMES,
    LAMBDA(VALIDDATES,AMOUNTS,
     TEXT(SUM(FILTER(AMOUNTS,VALIDDATES>=START,VALIDDATES<=END)),"$#,##0.00")
    )(TEXT((DATES&" "&TIMES)+TUNEHOUR/24,DTFORMAT),IF(ISNUMBER(AMOUNTS),AMOUNTS,VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(AMOUNTS,"^\$(.+)"))))
   )(TEXT(INDEX(DATES,,1),DFORMAT),REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(DATES,,2),"Z",""))
  )(SPLIT(QUERY({DATES},SKIPBLANK),"T"),QUERY({AMOUNTS},SKIPBLANK),DFORMAT&" "&TFORMAT,TEXT(START,DFORMAT)&" 00:00:00",TEXT(END,DFORMAT)&" 23:59:59")
 )($B$5:$B,$C$5:$C,$B$1,$B$2,"yyyy-mm-dd","hh:mm:ss","WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",-6)
)
```

Where you enter a start date and an end date at `B1` & `B2` to sum up the amount with.

The provided date column will be deducted by 6 hours.

[image: B3]

What this formula does is...

1. format the date column into a valid date,
2. compare dates from step 1 with a given start and end date as filter condition,
3. filter the given amount column with conditions from step 2,
4. sum the result of filter from step 3 as an array,
5. format the output as price.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexreplace()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      weeknum( 
        regexreplace(B2:B, "([-\d]+)T(\d\d:\d\d).+", "$1 $2") 
        - 
        "6:00" 
      ), 
      C2:C 
    }, 
    "select Col1, avg(Col2) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label Col1 'week #' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to split the values and sum them. I can't understand fully what's the purpose of 19 in LEFT function, and why are you again splitting it? Maybe some approach similar to yours is use LEFT function with 10 characters for the date, and MID from 12th character to get the time. Then substract .25 for the 6 hours as you did, and ROUNDDOWN with 0 digits to get the only the day

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDDOWN(LEFT('Sheet1'!B:B,10)+MID('Sheet1'!B:B,12,8)-0.25,0))
```

[image]

And then you can insert it in your SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!C:C,ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDDOWN(LEFT(Sheet1!B:B,10)+MID(Sheet1!B:B,12,8)-0.25,0)),A1)
```

Comment: Depending on what you have in A1, you can add WEEKNUM inside ARRAYFORMULA, as player0 did. Or if you have the final date in A1 you can do SUMIFS to have "<="&A1 and ">"&(A1-7)

Comment: this is much cleaner than what I was trying to do, but got to the same end result. the sumif is still returning 0 and not matching anything for some reason, even though it does match. A1 is an end date, such as 12/2/2022. I have a list of days and trying to sum all from the list on Sheet1 that matches that date.

Comment: Could you please share a sample?